# Spring Framework - Using only JPA data repositories in existing application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have an existing application which I want to extend by an embedded database. I have some experience with 'raw' derby (writing the sql statements by myself). For this application I use eclipse with maven but no additional framework for the application itself.

I have no experience with the spring framework but I came accross JPA data repositories (spring-data-jpa from org.springframework.data) which seems for me the way to go. But is it possible to use for the moment for this application only the data repositories of spring? Or will this lead to changes in the existing Code as one can not use only the data repositories alone?

Comment: "Data repositories of Spring" what do you mean?

Comment: Yes you need to change existing code to add Spring repositories package to your project, if your existing project doesn't compliance with JPA.

Comment: Is JPA data repositories the correct terminus?

Comment: @HumanAlgorithm What means 'compliance with JPA'? I have no existing code for using a database, so this part will be completely new.

Comment: I believe your existing application is getting data from somewhere instead of database now. Then it will be minimum change in your existing code to get the data alone. Other than that its easy to integrate by just adding few repository classes, Spring application config file(xml or java class) and Spring jars.

Comment: Ok, but no change for starting the application or somewhere else which has nothing to do with the data which will now be stored in the database?

Comment: @Semaphor: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: @HumanAlgorithm Thank you very much!